# Kernel Oops when unregister jprobes on Android/ARM

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm, kernel-module, kprobe

I wrote a kernel module (see code below) for my Nexus 5 to trace some syscalls via kprobes (I have built a custom kernel that has kprobes enabled for this).

Occasionally, when unloading the module via `rmmod` my phone freezes and reboots. Trying to isolate the root cause of the bug, now in my module is nothing left except code to register a jprobe for the syscall do_fork (but the bug happens for other probed functions too) and unregister it when unloading (so, I think it is probably a kprobes bug on ARM rather than a Android specific problem). Maybe anyone can point me to a known bug in kprobes?

The logs about the kernel panic tell me about some paging problem `Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address c0193a2c`, where `c0193a2c` is actually the address of `do_fork`.

```
#include <linux/init.h>     
#include <linux/kernel.h>   
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kprobes.h>

long trace_do_fork(unsigned long clone_flags, unsigned long stack_start,
           struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long stack_size,
           int __user *parent_tidptr, int __user *child_tidptr)
{
    jprobe_return();
    return 0;
}

#define CREATE_JPROBE(victim, target)            \
        static struct jprobe jp_##victim = {         \
                .entry = (kprobe_opcode_t *) target, \
                .kp = {                  \
                        .symbol_name = #victim,      \
                },                   \
        }

CREATE_JPROBE(do_fork, trace_do_fork);

#define NUM_PROBES 1
static struct jprobe *jprobes[NUM_PROBES] = {
    &jp_do_fork,
};

static int __init droidtracer_init(void)
{
    int err;
    /* plant jprobes */  
    err = register_jprobes(jprobes, NUM_PROBES);
    if (err) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "RV; register_jprobes failed = %d\n", err);
        return err;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "RV; planted %d jprobes\n", NUM_PROBES);  

    return 0;
}

static void __exit droidtracer_exit(void)
{
    unregister_jprobes(jprobes, NUM_PROBES);    
}

module_init(droidtracer_init);
module_exit(droidtracer_exit);
```

Here is the output from cat `/proc/last_kmsg` on my Nexus 5:

```
[ 1967.788836] RV; planted 1 jprobes
[ 1967.908095] init: untracked pid 15957 exited with status 17
[ 1967.987314] type=1400 audit(1449702053.652:53): avc: denied { write } for pid=16008 comm="app_process32_o" name="system@framework@boot.art" dev="dm-0" ino=491522 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:dalvikcache_data_file:s0 tclass=file
[ 1968.102799] init: untracked pid 16001 exited with status 52
[ 1968.122856] init: untracked pid 15960 exited with status 0
[ 1968.330685] init: untracked pid 16008 exited with status 0
[ 1969.106371] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address c0193a2c
[ 1969.106418] pgd = c0004000
[ 1969.106489] [c0193a2c] *pgd=0001141e(bad)
[ 1969.106602] Internal error: Oops: 80d [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[ 1969.106642] Modules linked in: droidtracer(O-) [last unloaded: droidtracer]
[ 1969.106821] CPU: 3    Tainted: G           O  (3.4.0-g5170b88 #23)
[ 1969.106897] PC is at __patch_text+0x34/0x58
[ 1969.106939] LR is at mem_text_address_writeable+0xac/0xc4
[ 1969.106980] pc : [<c0a4db78>]    lr : [<c01166a4>]    psr: 20000093
[ 1969.106982] sp : e8d43ea0  ip : c0193000  fp : e8d43ebc
[ 1969.107088] r10: 00000001  r9 : dae8fde4  r8 : 00000001
[ 1969.107158] r7 : a0000013  r6 : dae8fe54  r5 : e1a0c00d  r4 : c0193a2c
[ 1969.107197] r3 : c113a4a4  r2 : c0007000  r1 : c0193a2c  r0 : c0193000
[ 1969.107238] Flags: nzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
[ 1969.107310] Control: 10c5787d  Table: 3558006a  DAC: 00000015
[ 1969.107350] 
[ 1969.107351] PC: 0xc0a4daf8:
[ 1969.107455] daf8  e89da9f8 e592300c e3a04002 e1a00004 e5813004 e89da9f8 e592300c e12fff33
[ 1969.107818] db18  e1a04000 e1a00004 e89da9f8 e592200c eaffff9c e1a02006 e3a07001 eaffff99
[ 1969.108213] db38  e1a04005 eaffffd1 c0b00670 e1a0c00d e92dd830 e24cb004 e24dd008 e1a04000
[ 1969.108575] db58  e24b0018 e1a05001 ebdb228f e1a00004 ebdb22a2 e30a34a4 e34c3113 e1a01004
[ 1969.108971] db78  e4815004 e1a00004 e5933010 e12fff33 ebdb22cb e24b0018 ebdb228e e24bd014
[ 1969.109340] db98  e89da830 e1a0c00d e92dd800 e24cb004 ebffffe5 e89da800 e1a0c00d e92dd800
[ 1969.109738] dbb8  e24cb004 e52de004 e8bd4000 e5902030 e5900014 e3c234ff e3120401 e1a03103
[ 1969.110132] dbd8  e2032402 e2622000 e1823003 12802004 e2800008 15812038 e0803003 e581303c
[ 1969.110504] 
[ 1969.110505] LR: 0xc0116624:
[ 1969.110610] 6624  e3a01000 e592200c e5c31014 e59221f0 e5922024 389da818 e59f1074 e1500001
[ 1969.111006] 6644  289da818 e1a01aa0 e3100601 e3c00eff e59f4058 e0822181 e3c0000f e583000c
[ 1969.111375] 6664  12820004 01a00002 e5832008 e5901000 15830008 e201c003 e5832004 e35c0002
[ 1969.111771] 6684  e5831010 189da818 e3c11902 e5801000 ee072f3a f57ff04f e594000c ebffda1c
[ 1969.112166] 66a4  e3a03001 e5c43014 e89da818 c0008000 c11ff920 c0b00000 e1a0c00d e92dd800
[ 1969.112534] 66c4  e24cb004 e52de004 e8bd4000 e59f302c e5d32014 e3520000 089da800 e5931008
[ 1969.112927] 66e4  e5930010 e5932004 e5810000 ee072f3a f57ff04f e593000c ebffda05 e89da800
[ 1969.113324] 6704  c11ff920 e1a0c00d e92dd830 e24cb004 e24dd008 e52de004 e8bd4000 e1a04000
[ 1969.113723] 
[ 1969.113724] SP: 0xe8d43e20:
[ 1969.113797] 3e20  c116efa0 c113c0d8 e8d43ee4 c0a4db78 20000093 ffffffff e8d43e8c 00000001
[ 1969.114190] 3e40  dae8fde4 00000001 e8d43ebc e8d43e58 c0a4c618 c010022c c0193000 c0193a2c
[ 1969.114558] 3e60  c0007000 c113a4a4 c0193a2c e1a0c00d dae8fe54 a0000013 00000001 dae8fde4
[ 1969.114950] 3e80  00000001 e8d43ebc c0193000 e8d43ea0 c01166a4 c0a4db78 20000093 ffffffff
[ 1969.115344] 3ea0  dae8df20 20000093 dae8fe40 00000003 e8d43ecc e8d43ec0 c0a4cabc c0a4db50
[ 1969.115739] 3ec0  e8d43ef4 e8d43ed0 c01f18c4 c0a4caa4 00000001 e8d42000 c241bd24 00000000
[ 1969.116103] 3ee0  dae8fe40 c01f17d8 e8d43fbc e8d43ef8 c01f1548 c01f17e4 c0a4ab08 c01c1eac
[ 1969.116497] 3f00  00000000 c241bd2c 00000000 00000000 618fcdfb 000001ca 00000001 c0a4b040
[ 1969.116894] 
[ 1969.116895] IP: 0xc0192f80:
[ 1969.116967] 2f80  e58732c0 e58732bc e58731ec e58731f0 e59c300c e59301ec e3500000 0a00000c
[ 1969.117366] 2fa0  e3140c01 0a00003d e2803028 e1932f9f e2822001 e1831f92 e3310000 1afffffa
[ 1969.117763] 2fc0  e3a03000 e580316c e5803170 e58701ec e58701f0 e1a00004 e1a01007 eb00a279
[ 1969.118129] 2fe0  e250a000 13a09000 0a000033 e59701ec e3500000 0a000000 ebfffca5 e51bc040
[ 1969.118527] 3000  e35c0000 1a000004 e30c1ec0 e34c1126 e591000c e59713c8 eb036498 e59703cc
[ 1969.118924] 3020  ebfffe62 e1a00007 eb042de4 e1a00007 eb00166d eaffffa8 e1a0000a eb042dfd
[ 1969.119284] 3040  e3500000 e58703bc 1affffbb e3e0a00b e3a09000 eafffff4 e30c1ec0 e34c1126
[ 1969.119648] 3060  e591001c e3a010d0 eb0362da f57ff05f e3500000 e58703cc 0a000223 e51bc03c
[ 1969.120044] 
[ 1969.120045] FP: 0xe8d43e3c:
[ 1969.120118] 3e3c  00000001 dae8fde4 00000001 e8d43ebc e8d43e58 c0a4c618 c010022c c0193000
[ 1969.120513] 3e5c  c0193a2c c0007000 c113a4a4 c0193a2c e1a0c00d dae8fe54 a0000013 00000001
[ 1969.120907] 3e7c  dae8fde4 00000001 e8d43ebc c0193000 e8d43ea0 c01166a4 c0a4db78 20000093
[ 1969.121275] 3e9c  ffffffff dae8df20 20000093 dae8fe40 00000003 e8d43ecc e8d43ec0 c0a4cabc
[ 1969.121646] 3ebc  c0a4db50 e8d43ef4 e8d43ed0 c01f18c4 c0a4caa4 00000001 e8d42000 c241bd24
[ 1969.122045] 3edc  00000000 dae8fe40 c01f17d8 e8d43fbc e8d43ef8 c01f1548 c01f17e4 c0a4ab08
[ 1969.122442] 3efc  c01c1eac 00000000 c241bd2c 00000000 00000000 618fcdfb 000001ca 00000001
[ 1969.122808] 3f1c  c0a4b040 c1131740 c1131740 00001f21 00000000 c112e450 c1131740 00000000
[ 1969.123204] 
[ 1969.123205] R0: 0xc0192f80:
[ 1969.123308] 2f80  e58732c0 e58732bc e58731ec e58731f0 e59c300c e59301ec e3500000 0a00000c
[ 1969.123673] 2fa0  e3140c01 0a00003d e2803028 e1932f9f e2822001 e1831f92 e3310000 1afffffa
[ 1969.124068] 2fc0  e3a03000 e580316c e5803170 e58701ec e58701f0 e1a00004 e1a01007 eb00a279
[ 1969.124464] 2fe0  e250a000 13a09000 0a000033 e59701ec e3500000 0a000000 ebfffca5 e51bc040
[ 1969.124827] 3000  e35c0000 1a000004 e30c1ec0 e34c1126 e591000c e59713c8 eb036498 e59703cc
[ 1969.125223] 3020  ebfffe62 e1a00007 eb042de4 e1a00007 eb00166d eaffffa8 e1a0000a eb042dfd
[ 1969.125618] 3040  e3500000 e58703bc 1affffbb e3e0a00b e3a09000 eafffff4 e30c1ec0 e34c1126
[ 1969.126013] 3060  e591001c e3a010d0 eb0362da f57ff05f e3500000 e58703cc 0a000223 e51bc03c
[ 1969.126383] 
[ 1969.126384] R1: 0xc01939ac:
[ 1969.126489] 39ac  1afffffa e587a454 eafffdcb c11cbe80 c11688f0 c1168f54 c1134040 c0d6c9ac
[ 1969.126856] 39cc  c1142f38 c113c0d8 c112e5c0 c11cceb8 c0d6c96c c126cee4 c0199c94 c0d6c980
[ 1969.127253] 39ec  c0d6c994 e1a0c00d e92dd800 e24cb004 e52de004 e8bd4000 e1a0200d e3c23d7f
[ 1969.127649] 3a0c  e3a01000 e3c3303f e1a02001 e593c00c e58c029c e593000c eb0079f6 e89da800
[ 1969.128050] 3a2c  e1a0c00d e92dddf0 e24cb004 e24dd020 e52de004 e8bd4000 e3100201 e1a04000
[ 1969.128419] 3a4c  e1a06001 e1a07002 e1a05003 0a00000d e3100801 1a00005c e3a00015 eb002f48
[ 1969.128817] 3a6c  e3500000 0a00009c e3a00007 eb002f44 e3500000 0a000098 e3a00006 eb002f40
[ 1969.129217] 3a8c  e3500000 0a000094 e5978040 e218800f 13a08000 1a000012 e3140502 1a000010
[ 1969.129587] 
[ 1969.129588] R2: 0xc0006f80:
[ 1969.129662] 6f80  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1969.130063] 6fa0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1969.130431] 6fc0  349ec811 349ecc11 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1969.130828] 6fe0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 36be7811 36be7c11
[ 1969.131223] 7000  0001141e 0011140e 0021940e 0031940e 0041940e 0051940e 0061940e 0071940e
[ 1969.131587] 7020  0081940e 0091940e 00a1940e 00b1941e 00c1941e 00d1941e 00e1941e 00f1941e
[ 1969.131955] 7040  0101940e 0111141e 0121141e 0131141e 0141141e 0151141e 0161141e 0171141e
[ 1969.132352] 7060  0181141e 0191141e 01a1141e 01b1141e 01c1141e 01d1141e 01e1141e 01f1141e
[ 1969.132748] 
[ 1969.132749] R3: 0xc113a424:
[ 1969.132821] a424  6f0565ba 31608756 fbbc260d 3ab7828b f06b23d0 ae0ec13c 64d26067 20dba45a
[ 1969.133212] a444  36c8dc43 292974a6 331e896e d0b7bc08 06876874 d288e84f 1672f9f9 9cc6ff8c
[ 1969.133578] a464  178284ea 4f454bb9 9fa41d71 91e87642 cd987452 16bf87ac 124bab00 00000001
[ 1969.133949] a484  00000000 20fd1972 c010d2f0 ffffffff 00000009 0007b0d7 c01184c0 c0118474
[ 1969.134351] a4a4  c0118220 c01182cc c01182e4 c01182e4 c01182e8 c01182e8 c0118364 c011844c
[ 1969.134752] a4c4  c011845c c011839c c01183e4 c0118418 00000022 ffffffff 00000000 fa002000
[ 1969.135119] a4e4  fa003000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1969.135516] a504  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1969.135878] 
[ 1969.135879] R4: 0xc01939ac:
[ 1969.135952] 39ac  1afffffa e587a454 eafffdcb c11cbe80 c11688f0 c1168f54 c1134040 c0d6c9ac
[ 1969.136351] 39cc  c1142f38 c113c0d8 c112e5c0 c11cceb8 c0d6c96c c126cee4 c0199c94 c0d6c980
[ 1969.136747] 39ec  c0d6c994 e1a0c00d e92dd800 e24cb004 e52de004 e8bd4000 e1a0200d e3c23d7f
[ 1969.137116] 3a0c  e3a01000 e3c3303f e1a02001 e593c00c e58c029c e593000c eb0079f6 e89da800
[ 1969.137515] 3a2c  e1a0c00d e92dddf0 e24cb004 e24dd020 e52de004 e8bd4000 e3100201 e1a04000
[ 1969.137879] 3a4c  e1a06001 e1a07002 e1a05003 0a00000d e3100801 1a00005c e3a00015 eb002f48
[ 1969.138276] 3a6c  e3500000 0a00009c e3a00007 eb002f44 e3500000 0a000098 e3a00006 eb002f40
[ 1969.138644] 3a8c  e3500000 0a000094 e5978040 e218800f 13a08000 1a000012 e3140502 1a000010
[ 1969.139038] 
[ 1969.139039] R5: 0xe1a0bf8d:
[ 1969.139112] bf8c  5d02005d 5d04000a 00203d20 3d205d10 77656e20 72724120 29287961 5d1c003b
[ 1969.139509] bfac  6977202c 74206874 66206568 6f6c6c6f 676e6977 74696b20 000a3a73 003b5d02
[ 1969.139870] bfcc  203b5d03 5b5d1000 746c6127 74786574 3d205d27 0d002720 63275b5d 27646966
[ 1969.140267] bfec  203d205d 5d0d0027 6574275b 5d277478 27203d20 57165211 ff6aff65 51105110
[ 1969.140636] c00c  ff64ff64 54144f0f ff6aff65 55154e0d ff6bff63 510e4f0d ff64ff63 48055310
[ 1969.141036] c02c  ff5bff66 55125512 ff68ff68 5412520f ff68ff65 520f5613 ff65ff69 510e5411
[ 1969.141431] c04c  ff64ff67 5410510d ff65ff63 5512510d ff67ff63 500d5916 ff63ff6c 54115714
[ 1969.141799] c06c  ff67ff6a 5412500d ff68ff63 59165512 ff6cff68 4f0d5310 ff63ff66 54115613
[ 1969.142201] c08c  ff67ff69 53105512 ff66ff68 54125412 ff68ff68 53105412 ff66ff68 53105512
[ 1969.142601] 
[ 1969.142603] R6: 0xdae8fdd4:
[ 1969.142676] fdd4  dae8fde0 c01f1944 c01f16ec c113b004 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1969.143074] fdf4  00000000 dae8fdf8 dae8fdf8 c0a49acc c116b588 c113b004 dae8fe40 dae8fe3c
[ 1969.143472] fe14  dae8fe20 c01f1a84 c01f1900 c0a4ca98 bf00a0f4 c113b004 c113b004 dae8fe74
[ 1969.143841] fe34  dae8fe40 c01f1ba8 c01f1a50 c0a4ca98 bf00a0f4 00000004 c113b004 00000003
[ 1969.144239] fe54  00000002 c113b004 bf00a0f4 c0a4ca98 00000000 dae8fe94 dae8fe78 c01f1c1c
[ 1969.144633] fe74  c01f1b04 c0b09a34 bf00a0f4 bf00a0f4 00000001 dae8fea4 dae8fe98 c0a4cc34
[ 1969.145028] fe94  c01f1bf4 dae8fec4 dae8fea8 c0a4ecf4 c0a4cc10 00000000 00000001 00000001
[ 1969.145392] feb4  bf00a0f4 dae8fee4 dae8fec8 c0a4f03c c0a4ec80 c0a49acc c0a49748 00000001
[ 1969.145787] 
[ 1969.145788] R9: 0xdae8fd64:
[ 1969.145859] fd64  c112ed38 00000002 dae8e000 c113b004 c113b868 c112ed24 c112ed38 dae8e000
[ 1969.146259] fd84  c113c0d8 dae8fdac dae8fd98 c0a4afe4 c0a4a71c 00000002 00000004 dae8fddc
[ 1969.146656] fda4  dae8fdb0 c01f17c4 c0a4afb0 dae8fde4 c113b004 c01f17d8 dae8fe40 c01f17d8
[ 1969.147056] fdc4  bf00a0f0 dae8e000 00000000 dae8fe1c dae8fde0 c01f1944 c01f16ec c113b004
[ 1969.147422] fde4  00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 dae8fdf8 dae8fdf8 c0a49acc
[ 1969.147822] fe04  c116b588 c113b004 dae8fe40 dae8fe3c dae8fe20 c01f1a84 c01f1900 c0a4ca98
[ 1969.148220] fe24  bf00a0f4 c113b004 c113b004 dae8fe74 dae8fe40 c01f1ba8 c01f1a50 c0a4ca98
[ 1969.148591] fe44  bf00a0f4 00000004 c113b004 00000003 00000002 c113b004 bf00a0f4 c0a4ca98
[ 1969.148958] Process migration/3 (pid: 16049, stack limit = 0xe8d422f0)
[ 1969.149029] Stack: (0xe8d43ea0 to 0xe8d44000)
[ 1969.149071] 3ea0: dae8df20 20000093 dae8fe40 00000003 e8d43ecc e8d43ec0 c0a4cabc c0a4db50
[ 1969.149144] 3ec0: e8d43ef4 e8d43ed0 c01f18c4 c0a4caa4 00000001 e8d42000 c241bd24 00000000
[ 1969.149216] 3ee0: dae8fe40 c01f17d8 e8d43fbc e8d43ef8 c01f1548 c01f17e4 c0a4ab08 c01c1eac
[ 1969.149257] 3f00: 00000000 c241bd2c 00000000 00000000 618fcdfb 000001ca 00000001 c0a4b040
[ 1969.149330] 3f20: c1131740 c1131740 00001f21 00000000 c112e450 c1131740 00000000 00000000
[ 1969.149403] 3f40: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c01c0214
[ 1969.149475] 3f60: 00000000 00000001 00000000 dc961de4 dc961de0 00000013 00000013 00000000
[ 1969.149518] 3f80: 00000000 dc961dd0 c241bd24 20fd1972 00000013 dc961dd0 c241bd24 c01f1484
[ 1969.149592] 3fa0: 00000013 00000000 00000000 00000000 e8d43ff4 e8d43fc0 c01b5f58 c01f1490
[ 1969.149664] 3fc0: 00000000 c241bd24 00000000 00000000 e8d43fd0 e8d43fd0 00000000 dc961dd0
[ 1969.149736] 3fe0: c01b5ec0 c0107c20 00000000 e8d43ff8 c0107c20 c01b5ecc 00000000 00000000
[ 1969.149784] [<c0a4db78>] (__patch_text+0x34/0x58) from [<c0a4cabc>] (__arch_disarm_kprobe+0x24/0x2c)
[ 1969.149863] [<c0a4cabc>] (__arch_disarm_kprobe+0x24/0x2c) from [<c01f18c4>] (stop_machine_cpu_stop+0xec/0x11c)
[ 1969.149940] [<c01f18c4>] (stop_machine_cpu_stop+0xec/0x11c) from [<c01f1548>] (cpu_stopper_thread+0xc4/0x1a8)
[ 1969.150018] [<c01f1548>] (cpu_stopper_thread+0xc4/0x1a8) from [<c01b5f58>] (kthread+0x98/0xa4)
[ 1969.150096] [<c01b5f58>] (kthread+0x98/0xa4) from [<c0107c20>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
[ 1969.150139] Code: ebdb22a2 e30a34a4 e34c3113 e1a01004 (e4815004) 
[ 1969.150239] ---[ end trace a138dd63f3507951 ]---
[ 1969.150279] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
[ 1970.712851] SMP: failed to stop secondary CPUs
[ 1971.713234] Rebooting in 5 seconds..
[ 1978.277336] SMP: failed to stop secondary CPUs
[ 1978.277440] Going down for restart now
[ 1978.278139] Calling SCM to disable SPMI PMIC arbiter

No errors detected
Boot info:
Last boot reason: kernel_panic
```

Comment: If you look in detail, you may well find that you are attempting to utilize the code you just removed from the kernel, or something like that.  Presumably you are doing this kprobe hack for lab type investigations - does it ultimately matter if you cannot remove it without rebooting?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I used jprobe in the lab so far, now my goal is to build something for real rooted phones, so users can trace app behaviour; thus, robustness matters. Also, I am curious:  is it a real bug, as the documentation doesn't mention the kernel might panic? Calling `unregister_jprobes()`  should be all I need to do to safely clean up the module before unload. I can safely remove the module most of the time (that's why I haven't noticed before). Might you please give more details on what you mean with "utilise the code I just removed from the kernel"? Thanks.